# Unable to login Root account in BOSS Linux?

Tags: linux, ssh, passwords, user-accounts, root

I use EduBOSS_Linux 3.0.
I want to Login my BOSS Linux with root account.
I try combination of default password 
**root ---- root**
boss ---- root
root ---- boss
boss ---- boss

**root ---- root** is working for got root privilege during software installation but that username and password combination not work for login root account.
1) Why accurate username and password also not able to login in root account.
2) How can I login in root account of Boss Linux?
3) How can change password of root account of BOSS Linux by Admin Account?
[I post screen shot here](http://edubosslinux.blogspot.in/2015/06/blog-post.html)
[**I Upload images here with description and details**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzbNI.jpg)

Comment: does sudo su work?

Comment: yes! all thinks are work. But when I try to Login with root account. It shows wrong password. Actually password is accurate.

Comment: Have you try to change root password and try to login?

Comment: I try to change root password I use same method like **Kuser** in REDhat.

Comment: change it by login in your account, then sudo su - and the passwd

Comment: @RomeoNinov How ?

Comment: @MadhavNikam, please check my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24552/discussion-between-madhav-nikam-and-romeo-ninov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are... There's intentionally no root password. You're supposed to use sudo as needed. THIS IS A GOOD THING. It means that you're less likely to do the wrong thing as root, is more secure and sudo let's you do all the same things anyway.

If you must, sudo su (with a user who can sudo, typically the first user you add during install) will let you do things as root, including setting a root password. You don't need to /shouldn't

From the additional information in the comments, you're running  a modern version of *gnome*, and gdm. I don't use gnome, but with that information, and that BOSS is a debian derivative, we can find an answer.

Many distros including debian, which BOSS is based off of disable root logins for graphical logins. This is a very sensible thing (and in the old days, KDE would have a red background and a bomb symbol when you did this). Once again, this is a terrible idea and you should generally not run anything as root. There's usually something that emulates sudo (gksudo?). Alternately you need to open up your login manager config file, and comment out the line that disallows root logins. I re-iterate this is a *terrible* idea, and you probably should not do it.

Have I said a few times its a bad idea? Good.

If you still want to do this its a file called `/etc/pam.d/gdm3` and you need to comment a line out that says `#auth     required     pam_succeed_if.so  user  != root   quiet_success`. My [source](http://anandmpandit.blogspot.sg/2013/07/how-to-enable-root-login-in-gnome-on.html) suggests that you use vi, but any text editor should work

Comment: no! In BOOS root is by default password. But I again add some images of screen shot for better clarification. Here not privilege to do that.

Comment: [I update link with proper format](http://edubosslinux.blogspot.in/)

Comment: Updated the answer. The additional information should be in your *question*. If you can't upload images, just upload them to imgur, and post a link in your question to them, and someone will inline them for you shortly.

Comment: @Journeman Geek I upload Images [here](http://imgur.com/gallery/2ru5b/new)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to change the password for root as seems there is no at the moment:

1. Login as your user
2. switch to root

   sudo su -
3. change root password

   passwd

The open new virtual terminal and try to login as root

To troubleshooting you can check the logs in /var/log in messages or auth files

Comment: OK i try and report here. just 1 min

Comment: I change password. But still not able to login in root.

Comment: Check my edited answer